# iPhone UIImagePickerController problem: want to show UIActivityIndicatorView after hit "Use" button

Tags: iphone, android-activity, uiimagepickercontroller, progress

When Apple introduced version 3.0 of the iPhone OS the UIImagePickerController changed slighty: it no longer provides an activity or progress indicator after the user confirms a recently taken photo.  In a nutshell, you now
- take a picture, 
- decide it's ok and 
- hit the "Use" button and wait.
There is no indication as to whether you have actually hit the "Use" button or not.  Often, I hit it several times since I am unsure if I actually hit it or not.  After a few seconds, you see the image or the image becomes available via delegate connections, e.g.

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

My question is this:
- How do I display an UIActivityIndicatorView right after the "Use" button is selected? Or, how to I insert my own code by intercepting the "Use" button callback?  I've searched the web and expected many people to have the same problem but have not found a solution yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly you cant intercept this call. I say this because there is no delegate method in UIImagePickerController that will tell the delegate about the push of Use button. Since you cant change the code in UIImagePickerController i dont think there is anything one can do. Apple mightimprove this with 3.1, i heard that they have done some work on UIImagePickerController...

Comment: from what I was able to see from looking at the 3.1 api files you still can't, but that could all change Wednesday

Answer (score 0):

What you can essentially do is add your UIActivityInidicatior to the UIImagePicker view before you dismiss it.

Here is a similar thing I'm doing while I'm compressing the image after the user has pushed the use button. Notice the NSTimer - it's a nifty trick to cause the iphone to actually show the UI you're adding:
on didFinishPickingImage:

```
//this will add the UIActivityInidicatior to the picker view

(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo { 
 showActivity(@"Compressing Image", picker.view);

 //this is a hack so the progress label will show up

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.0f
                                     target: self
                                   selector: @selector(compress:)
                                   userInfo: image
                                    repeats: NO];
}




//the Compress method

(void) compress:(NSTimer *)inTimer {
 NSAutoreleasePool *_pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

 //do some work


   [[self getPicker] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 

//dismiss the view we added to the picker
 showActivity(nil, [self getPicker].view);

 [_pool release];

}
```

Note that I keep the `UIImagePickerController` outside, so I can reference it from the invoked message.

`showActivity` is a simple method that adds some UI to the given view.

Comment: can you post your complete code? i'm also loking for such a similar thing

Answer (score 0):

Through dispatch queue concepts,

when you press use button it will dismiss pickercontroller in one thread and showing activity indicator code will run in another thread. In between,  you can call your own method.

> dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
>   0), ^{
>
> ```
> dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
>
>   indicator=[[MBProgressHUD alloc]init];
>   indicator.labelText=@"Loading";
>   indicator = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
>   [indicator show:YES];
>
>
> });
>
> // Put here the code to resize the image
> [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setPath:) withObject:image];
>
> dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
>   [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
>
> });
> ```

**OR**

if you want to show activity indicator in uiimagepickercontroller means just change this line

> ```
>   indicator=[[MBProgressHUD alloc]init];
>   indicator.labelText=@"Loading";
>   indicator = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:picker.cameraOverlayView animated:YES];
>   [indicator show:YES];
> ```